# Reformat string containing uk postcode using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I format a string using Javascript to match a regex?

I am using UK postcodes which could match any of the following

```
N1 3LD
EC1A 3AD
GU34 8RR
```

I have the following regex which validates a string correctly, but I am unsure how to use the regex as a mask to format `EC1A3AD` to `EC1A 3AD` / `GU348RR` to `GU34 8RR` / `N13LD` to `N1 3LD`.

My regex is `/^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9A-Za-z]{1,2}[ ]?[0-9]{0,1}[A-Za-z]{2}$/`

Thank you

Comment: what do you exactly mean with "how to use the regex as a mask" ?

Comment: I would like to be able to convert the string to match the regex.  E.G. if I have a regex to validate a string matches, I would like to be able to format a string accordingly (primarily in this case to insert a space in the relevant part of the postcode)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use the regular expression `/^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?)\s*(\d[A-Z]{2})$/` you can extract the two parts of the postcode and reassemble them with an intervening space.

```js
var list = ['N13LD', 'EC1A3AD', 'GU348RR'];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var parts = list[i].match(/^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?)\s*(\d[A-Z]{2})$/);
  parts.shift();
  alert(parts.join(' '));
}
```

**output**

```
N1 3LD
EC1A 3AD
GU34 8RR
```

Comment: This made it idiot proof and worked with no need to think.  Thanks to both.

Comment: @PaulChopsHelyer  you're not supposed to avoid thinking, that's why I didn't spoon feed you a whole function.

Comment: Thank you Alnitak, however my "not thinking" comment may have been a little flippant and taken wrongly.  A functional example allows me to see and learn at the same time.  Apologies if you feel this is not the way to do it, but having spent a few fruitless hours trying to piece together something from various examples that I did not understand, this has now led me to be able to adapt Borodin's example to suit my requirements. Thank you again for your help, it really is appreciated.

Comment: Great answer & simple, straight forward solution. I've used your logic above in my much messier answer below with credit to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put braces around the bits separated by the optional space:

```
/^([A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9A-Za-z]{1,2})[ ]?([0-9]{0,1}[A-Za-z]{2})$/
```

However I think the regexp is wrong...  The above regexp splits "N13LD" as "N13", "LD".

I suspect the errant part is the `{0,1}` before the two trailing letters - there must AFAIK be exactly one digit there:

```
var re = /^([A-Z]{1,2}[\dA-Z]{1,2})[ ]?(\d[A-Z]{2})$/i; // case insensitive
```

The grouping allows the `string.match(regexp)` function to return a result which includes an entry for each matching group:

```
> "N13LD".match(re);
["N13LD", "N1", "3LD"]

> "GU348RR".match(re);
["GU348RR", "GU34", "8RR"]

> "EC1A3AD".match(re);
["EC1A3AD", "EC1A", "3AD"]
```

To get your result, just use trivial string concatenation to join the 2nd and 3rd element from each result together.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak,

So what syntax would I use to get a string of "N1 3LD" from "N13LD" from your example?

Comment: @PaulChopsHelyer just take the 2nd and 3rd elements from the result of `.match()`.

Comment: @Alnitak: It may massage your ego to think that I plagiarised your solution, but believe me that is not the case. There are only so many ways to write such a regular expression and mine is about as different from yours as it could be while doing a very similar thing. Venting your frustration at both me and the OP will bring you neither admiration nor reputation points.

Comment: @Borodin fair enough, but it rather looked that way from here seeing as you also corrected the OP's mistake but didn't mention that you had done so.

Comment: @Alnitak: if you look at the edit history you will see that I haven't changed the OP's question either.

Comment: @Borodin I wasn't talking about the question.

Comment: @Alnitak: Ah, I see. You mean the regex in my solution doesn't have the problem that the one in the OP's question does? Well I live in Norfolk, England and know very well what a UK postcode looks like. I used that information to write my solution and referred to neither the OP's regex nor yours. A little local knowledge is always useful!

Comment: @Borodin yeah, that was the one.  Apologies for coming on strong - it just rankled when I had already given all the information required but you got the accepted answer just for adding a trivial bit of string concatenation ;-)

Comment: @Borodin oh, and FWIW, neither version is 100% correct ;) They both accept several strings that aren't actually legal.  See http://devsac.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/uk-postcode-regular-expression.html

Comment: @Alnitak: yeah but it matches all *patterns* that a UK postcode can have. The first two letters are an abbreviation for the post town (basically the local collection centre) so for instance `NR` is Norwich and `BS` is Bristol. There is no town `XX` etc. Thanks for the link - it's bookmarked. Also don't feel too bad cos while I got an accept you got an upvote so we're almost even :)

Comment: @Borodin yeah, I'm British too :)  Upvotes are nice, but accepts are better when you hit the rep cap most days ;-)

Comment: However if I was to use this:
"asas N13LD".match(re) I would get null :(

Answer (score 1):

I've used the excellent answer from @borodin above to create a UK postcode as-you-type formatter. Note, this does not validate the postcode, just formats it according to borodin's regex as the user types.

```js
var txtPc = $("#postcode");
var outputCount = 0;
var jigCount = 0;
var postcodePauseTime = 500;

txtPc.on("keydown", function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.which;

  var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
  var isAlphaNumeric = //key.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i);
    (
      (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) ||
      (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||
      ([189, 190, 8, 46, 9].indexOf(keyCode) > -1) ||
      (keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40)
    );

  return !!isAlphaNumeric;
});
// handle click and add class
txtPc.on("keyup", function(e) {
  PostcodeCalculateFormat(txtPc);
});

txtPc.on("blur", function() {
  PostcodeCalculateFormat(txtPc);
});

function PostcodeCalculateFormat(txtPc) {
  (function(index, txtPc) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      //prevent interferance from other keypresses by returning out of this closure
      if (index != jigCount) return;
      var isFocused = ($('#' + txtPc.attr('id') + ':focus')[0] == document.activeElement);
      var postcodeText = txtPc.val().toUpperCase(); /// + key;
      var origSpacePos = postcodeText.indexOf(" ");
      postcodeText = postcodeText.replace(/[\W_]+/g, "");
      var parts = postcodeText.match(/^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?)\s*(\d[A-Z]{2})$/i);
      //if unable to match the lot, try the first part only with less strict reg
      if (!parts)
        parts = postcodeText.match(/^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?)\s*(.*)$/i);
      if (parts) {
        var caretPos = 0;
        if (isFocused)
          caretPos = getCaretPosition(txtPc[0]).start;
        parts.shift();
        var newVal = parts.join(' ');
        if (newVal == txtPc.val())
          return;
        output(newVal);
        txtPc.val(newVal);
        var spacePos = newVal.indexOf(" ");
        if (isFocused) {
          if (caretPos >= spacePos && origSpacePos == -1)
            caretPos++;

          setCaretPosition(txtPc[0], caretPos, caretPos);
        }
      }
    }, postcodePauseTime);
  }(++jigCount, txtPc));
}

function output(str) {
  $("#listOutput").prepend("<li>[" + (++outputCount) + "] " + str + "</li>");
}

function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
  // IE < 9 Support
  if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var rangelen = range.text.length;
    range.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);
    var start = range.text.length - rangelen;
    return {
      'start': start,
      'end': start + rangelen
    };
  }
  // IE >=9 and other browsers
  else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0') {
    return {
      'start': ctrl.selectionStart,
      'end': ctrl.selectionEnd
    };
  } else {
    return {
      'start': 0,
      'end': 0
    };
  }
}


function setCaretPosition(ctrl, start, end) {
  // IE >= 9 and other browsers
  if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
    ctrl.focus();
    ctrl.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  }
  // IE < 9
  else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
    var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', end);
    range.moveStart('character', start);
    range.select();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: silver;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Sample postcodes to type: 'BT92PE', 'EC1A3AD', 'GU348RR', 'N13LD'</div>

<div>
  Postcode: <input id="postcode" style="text-transform: uppercase; " />
</div>

<!-- for troubleshooting -->
<ul id="listOutput"></ul>
```

The caret get & set functions were taken straight from a stack overflow answer, which I can't find right now to give the user credit. I will look & update with a link if I can.

This does everything I want it to, but it's not a very elegant solution. I'm happy for somebody out there to revamp, enhance or improve on this. I'd like to see the result.

Improvement for future: if the caret is after the space, the backspace key should remove the space AND the alphanumeric character before it in one key press. (same idea for the delete button if the caret is in before the space.)